# Increased click area gets applied on the last view only

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm using this extension function to increase click area:

```
fun View.increaseHitArea() {
val parent = parent as View
parent.doOnLayout {
    val rect = Rect()
    getHitRect(rect)
    rect.top -= 50
    rect.left -= 50
    rect.bottom += 50
    rect.right += 50
    parent.touchDelegate = TouchDelegate(rect, this)
}}
```

And in the fragment:

```
binding.button1.increaseHitArea()
binding.button2.increaseHitArea()
binding.button3.increaseHitArea()
```

But it gets applied to the last view (button) only, I want to apply this to all of them, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TouchDelegate` is applied to the *parent* view, and a `View` can only have **one** `TouchDelegate`. It's basically handling the touch events for that area you define, and passing them on to the delegate (which passes them to the child view).

You'll either need to nest each `Button` inside a larger parent `View` (so each button has its own parent to add a delegate to), or write your own delegate class that can handle multiple children - which is obviously a lot more complicated! The source for `TouchDelegate` is [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/TouchDelegate.java) if it helps.

Or you could try doing something with [intercepting touch events](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/gestures/viewgroup#intercept) on the parent view, and if they're clicks within the area you want, you can call `performClick()` on the appropriate child view. I haven't done this and I feel like it could get a bit complex, since you need to avoid swallowing other touch events. And it won't play nice with accessibility features like *explore by touch* unless you implement the correct rect handling for the view hierarchy, as far as I'm aware

---

Honestly sticking each in its own `FrameLayout` or something (with `layout_gravity` on the button set to `center`) and applying delegates to those is the easiest answer.

Or you can create a `View` that's positioned above your button (both within the same parent), and set the delegate on *that* - so it's like an invisible touch area on top of your button, instead of something it has to be nested inside. Bear in mind `getHitRect()` gives you coordinates *within the parent*, so you might need to translate that to coordinates *within your touch-catching `View`*. The easiest way to handle it is just to make the `View` fill the parent, so their coordinates match:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="One"
    />

<View
    android:id="@+id/touchCatcher1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

The limitation here is that your `View` will be limited to the size of its parent, so if your button is right against the edge of its parent layout (say in the corner of a `CardView`) then you can't add a `View` in the same layout that will extend past its bounds. It might be possible to do something like that with clipping etc, but you might have to adjust the `Rect` coordinates.

The other option is to nest the `View` *outside* that layout, so it's not limited by those boundaries. Except now your issue is the coordinates inside the `View` and inside the `Button`'s parent don't match, so you'll have to adjust the coords from `getHitRect` to line up properly. At that point, you might just want to use that Rect's `width` and `height` to create a new `Rect` in the centre of your View

I know that's all a bit complex - there's no easy way that covers every situation, but you have options!

Comment: Very detailed answer, thank you for your efforts